# NGINX reverse proxy from internal IP with :PORT

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm running two apps on a raspberry pi on my local network (at 192.168.1.95). I want to access them through my browser like this:

```
192.168.1.95:3000 = App One
192.168.1.95:3001 = App Two
```

So my server blocks look like this:

```
# App One
server {
  listen *:3000;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
  }
}

# App Two
server {
  listen *:3001;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
  }
}
```

But, on my laptop, in the browser, when I navigate to 192.168.1.95:3000 it just spins forever. I restarted NGINX on my pi, and it didn't report any errors. What is it missing?

Edits:

1. I checked access logs and error logs. Nothing is there which makes
   me think my `192.168.1.95:3000` requests are not even getting to
   nginx.
2. I'm open to other solutions. I would go for a subdomain, but I don't
       want DNS involved. It's a single internal IP with multiple websites and tools on it. I don't think
       `subdomain.192.168.1.95` works.

**Solution**: I am an idiot. I had UFW firewall on my pi blocking everything except 22, 80, 443. I exposed the ports I wanted and I'm good to go, without even needing nginx.

Comment: did you check your logs (access and errors), it's always useful info in there.

Comment: Looked in both, and there's nothing there. It seems like the request is not even making it to nginx.

Comment: try to change both `listen *:3000;` and `listen *:3001;` to >> `listen 80;`

Comment: I changed to `listen 80` and it did nothing. I changed to `listen :80` and it said `no host in ":80" of the "listen" directive`, so then I tried `listen *:80` and got no errors, but it didn't do anything. If they're both on port 80, how does it know which app to route the request to?

Comment: @deepcell - Solved it. It helps to check your firewall rules... Thanks for helping.

Comment: usually i use `server_name <IP or DOMAIN>;` right after `listen 80;` directive and it works. Good you fixed it.